# How to iterate through this API return in React (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to create a function that iterate through all the results from an api and create another string[] with just the values from one of the properties.

The return:

```
{
    "projectId": 203,
    "components": [
        {
            "id": 10310,
            "name": "Play Challenges",
            "quantity": 24.07
        },
        {
            "id": 10301,
            "name": "My Creation",
            "quantity": 12.96
        }]
}
```

I've tried this:

```
 const content: string[] = data.map((components : any ) => {
            return components.name
        });
```

but I get an error saying that

> Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: try `yourObject.components.map(c => c.name)`

Comment: You get a single object. That single object has a property called `components`. So you need `data.components.map`. And it's a VERY GOOD IDEA to not use `any`. If you [used proper types](https://tsplay.dev/NnlZdW) in your code, you'd have had compile time hints.

Comment: Tried this one: try yourObject.components.map(c => c.name) – 
It says: 
Property 'components' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)

Comment: Then for whatever reason TS believes that your object is an array of strings, rather than what you showed. Either TS is misinformed or it's correct and you have something different.

Comment: Yes, on my reducer i'm saying the return from the API is a string[]

interface State {
    loading: boolean;
    error: string | null;
    data: string[];
}

Comment: Then it's wrong because the object you've showed is not an array of strings. Again - use proper types.

Comment: thx :) 
What type of return should I add so that I can iterate through all the components and get their name ?

I would like to have in the end something like this: 
const component: string[] = ["Play Challenges", "My Creation"];

Comment: [See my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605156/how-to-iterate-through-this-api-return-in-react-typescript?noredirect=1#comment133386121_75605156)

Comment: @VLAZ I've tried your solution but didn't work, i'm guessing is because of the return on my reducer that I define as string[]

interface State {
    loading: boolean;
    error: string | null;
    data: string[];
}

const initialState = {
    loading: true,
    error: null,
    data: []
}
const openIssuesByComponentReducer = (state: State = initialState, action: Action): State => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case OpenIssuesByComponentActionType.FETCH_OPEN_ISSUES_BY_COMPONENTS_SUCESS:
            return { loading: false, error: null,  data: action.payload };
    }
};

Comment: [As I already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605156/how-to-iterate-through-this-api-return-in-react-typescript?noredirect=1#comment133386349_75605156) that's wrong. Yet again - use proper types. If you add random types then you'd be getting random problems.